# Tinymce remove &lt; and &gt;

Tags: tinymce

Im using tinymce in version 5.1.0 and trying to use plugin codesample for display part of codes but editor keep removing my < and > elements.

Code example:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
```

When i use that plugin and paste this code its ok

```
<pre class="language-markup"><code>#include &lt;Wire.h&gt;
#include &lt;Adafruit_GFX.h&gt;
#include &lt;Adafruit_SSD1306.h&gt;</code></pre>
```

But after saving my article its look like this:

```
<pre class="language-markup"><code>#include 
#include 
#include </code></pre>
```

How i can stop editor from removing this ?